# QUERY SQL BI analysis

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out how can do this BI table with a couple data i got, the thing is i'm doing by query consulting the DB(Oracle 11g).

Some have and idea of how can i do it's BI?

Rango = (quantity of transaction) for example: Range - 1 to 10 transactions

Clásica, Oro, Platino and so on = (quantity of unique clients who made those transaction) for example: how many clients are in the range of 1 to 10 transactions

[image]

my attempt

```
select case 
        when 
            count(case when code = transaction then 1 end) between 1 and 10 then '1 - 10'
        when 
            count(case when code = transaction then 1 end) between 11 and 19 then '11 - 19'
   end "RANGE"
  ,count(distinct case when producto = clasica then cliente end) clasica
  ,count(distinct case when producto = oro then cliente end) oro
from DB
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: @DavidAldridge the range